# Retornar um campo específico do XML

Tags: python, xml

Estou criando um programa que tem como objetivo obter dados de um XML, estou usando `xml.etree.ElementTree` para isso, mas não estou conseguindo criar um `for` para chamar as tags `cEAN` e `qCom`.

O XML usado:

```
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<infNFe versao="4.00" Id="NFe35200823520039000135550010000031451090031450">
<ide>
...
</ide>
<emit>
...
</emit>
<dest>
...
</dest>
<det nItem="1">
<prod>
<cProd>01.304</cProd>
<cEAN>7898338312758</cEAN>
<xProd>AF QUADRIAXIAL 6 QR6 HURRICANE</xProd>
<NCM>85182100</NCM>
<CEST>0105700</CEST>
<CFOP>5405</CFOP>
<uCom>par</uCom>
<qCom>60.0000</qCom>
<vUnCom>53.6000000000</vUnCom>
<vProd>3216.00</vProd>
<cEANTrib>7898338312758</cEANTrib>
<uTrib>par</uTrib>
<qTrib>60.0000</qTrib>
<vUnTrib>53.6000000000</vUnTrib>
<indTot>1</indTot>
</prod>
<imposto>
...
</imposto>
<infAdProd>7898338312758</infAdProd>
</det>
```

O que já tentei fazer:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("C:\\Users\\Expedição\\Videos\\XML\\xml_teste1.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for det in root.findall('det'):
  quantidade = det.find('qCom').text
  EAN = det.find('cEAN').text
  print (quantidade,EAN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

São basicamente dois problemas:

- [Segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements), `findall` procura pelos elementos que são filhos diretos do elemento em questão. Como a tag `det` está dentro de `infNFe`, que por sua vez está dentro de `NFe`, ela não é encontrada. Mas isso pode ser corrigido usando [XPath](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) (no caso, seria `.//nome_da_tag`).
- O namespace `http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe` também faz parte do nome da tag, e deve ser usado na string de busca.

Então ficaria:

```
for det in root.findall('.//{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}det'):
    quantidade = det.find('.//{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}qCom').text
    EAN = det.find('.//{http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe}cEAN').text
    print(quantidade, EAN)
```

Mas digitar o namespace para todas as tags pode ser um pouco chato, então você pode criar um dicionário que mapeia este namespace para um nome mais curto:

```
ns = {'nfe': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}
for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    quantidade = det.find('.//nfe:qCom', ns).text
    EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text
    print(quantidade, EAN)
```

Assim, o dicionário mapeia o namespace `http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe` para a chave `nfe`, e nas strings de busca basta colocar `nfe:nome_da_tag`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, esclareceu o conceito de hierarquia,vlw

Comment: pode me tirar uma duvida?desta forma escrita acima você chama todos `cEAN` mais é possível chamar só de um produto especifico.

Comment: @ValterFerreira Não sei se entendi, mas se quer só de um produto, vc pode buscar a respectiva tag, ver o valor dela e só buscar o cEAN dele (`if nome_produto == 'bla': busca o cEAN`, ou algo assim). Uma vez que vc sabe como buscar qualquer tag, dá pra fazer a lógica que vc quiser. Se não for isso, talvez valha a pena [fazer outra pergunta](/questions/ask)